# Disable scrolling on Soft Keyboard launch

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, web

I've been struggling with this for several days. I have a very simple page in my mobile app with a textarea input and when I click on it the soft keyboard appears and scrolls the header of my page out of view. Is there a way to prevent this default scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Your is the default functionality of Phones, When user completes typing the screen automatically scroll backs, Kindly check it, If it works please reply.

Comment: Yeah it does, but the point is to keep the header visible at all times.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-forms-b.html, if solves your problem i will change the answer so it can help others, Scrolling cant be stopped